# Magento does not remember country choice

Tags: php, magento

We use Magento in our website. The expected behavior is: when a user visits our website for the first time, a country selection page is shown. When he visits in the future, the system will show the home page using his previous country choice.

However, our website has a problem such that when a user visits the 2nd time, the country selection page is still shown.

Does anybody know which page I should modify to store the country choice and redirect the home page?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705087/magento-save-visitor-store-choice-in-cookies). You need to set cookie(when user comes at first time) and when check if it was
seted,  make redirect as you want. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711006/magento-remember-choice-in-cookies-radio) some example, you can see the script and just set the cookie.

Comment: Hi, sergio, I went through your link but I am confused about which file I should modify. Is head.php located in /magmi/web? Thanks a lot!